# Low Speed copy from SQL Server to ORACLE

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

My computers architecture:

1. SQL Server
2. ORACLE Server
3. Server running SSIS packages

I construct ETL solution that copy's data from SQL Server to ORACLE based on ADO.NET provider.

But my speed of copy is about - 600 000 rows per hour (I have 6 000 000 rows).

I want to improve my copying speed. Try change parameters `DefaultBuffersize`, `DefaultBufferMaxRows`, `batchsize`.

Try to import first from SQL Server to `.CSV`, then to Oracle. The speed is the same. Speed retrieving data from SQL Server tables is 600 000 rows per minute.

What can I do to improve speed copying to Oracle?

Comment: How big are your rows? What's the networking speed? (I had a similar issue once, and it turned out to be that one segment of the network had failed down to 10mbps. Once our IT department replaced a single networking cable and the network returned to gigabit, everything was fine...) Can't comment on ADO, though; I normally use OLEDB.

Comment: ~178 bytes in a row in CSV. Network speed IN Control panel->LAN network connection 10.0 Gbps (Intranet at work).

Comment: 178bytes/sec*600 000 rows/hour= 106 786 614 bytes in hour=29 663 bytes per second.

Comment: So presumably you can copy the CSV file (just as an actual file) from the SSIS machine to the Oracle server pretty fast?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have access to copy file to this Server. Have access to ping, time is<1ms.

Comment: I tested also importing file through Oracle SQL Developer, speed is the same. Does this mean that the problem is in the network? or configured poorly configured Oracle?

Comment: Could be all sorts of things; indexes, triggers, network, disk configuration... At this point I'd probably ask your Oracle DBA to look into things, he or she should be able to diagnose things more easily by trying directly copying the file in from the Oracle server, etc.

Comment: What type of destination component are you using in your ETL?  If it's a SqlCommand type it will be slow.  Direct writes are better.  If you have Sql Server Enterprise you get a license for the Oracle Attunity connectors which are far superior.